# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Remove Aggregate Root with DDD pattern in EFCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I try to use the DDD for my application, and when an aggregate root is create or edit I add the DomainEvent that will be raise in the SaveChange on me repository.

Now my problem is in delete operation, becase my entity root have the function to create or delete, but the for delete operation the only way is to call delete on repository, like this code that I have in one of my CommandHandler

```
entity.AddDomainEvent(new NodeRemovedPublicEvent(request.NodeId));
_repository.Delete(entity);
await _repository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

in this way i need to remember to create a domain event every time i use _repository.Delete(). I don't like this operation, there is a best practice for this situations?

EDIT 1: (dont' remove never).
I think this is the best way, to avoid transaction problem in delete, ecc...  In this way i need to implement a logical delete. In my case when the root identity is remove (logical remove it's the same) I need to remove other entity (logical delete). For do that i need to generete a domain event. If I don't raise that event, my entity have logical delete, ma the order entity don't. It's true that without that entity the order entity can't load, but i need to know that related entity is "linked" to entity logical removed.
For example if i remove ad User, and the user have the entity Food, i need to remove all Food entity assign to that user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your post, but you should take a look at this post by Udi Dahan: [Don’t Delete – Just Don’t](https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)

I think the best practice you are looking for is "not to delete" anything. Go back to the UL and discuss what actually happens instead of deleting something. I mean, in real-world things don't just "delete".

Comment: yes, i think this is the best way, to avoid transaction problem in delete, ecc...  But for example you say to check for delete. In my case when the root identity is remove (logical remove it's the same) i need to remove other entity. For do that i need to generete a domainevent. If i don't raise that event, my entity have logical delete, ma the order entity don't. It's true that without that entity the order entity can't load, but i need to know that related entity is "linked" to entity logical removed.

Comment: For example if i remove ad User, and the user have the entity Food, i need to remove all Food entity assign to that user.